# Spectrum of an element changes with extension of algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Assume that $B$ is a unital Banach algebra ($1$ is a unit), and $A \subset B$ is a closed subalgebra that contains $1$. Is it possible that there exists $a \in A$ such that $\sigma_A(a) \ne \sigma_B(a)$ ($\sigma_A$ is spectrum in the sense of algebra $A$, and the same thing is $\sigma_B$)? The inspiration for this question is that the spectral radius $\rho(a)$ does not depend on algebra ($A$ or $B$) since it is equal to $\lim ||a^n||^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

It is easy to see that $\sigma_B(a) \subset \sigma_A(a)$ for all $a \in A$. If $\lambda \notin \sigma_B(a)$ and $\lambda > \rho(a)$ then $(a - \lambda 1)^{-1}$ belongs to $A$ (since it can be approximated by polynomials of $a$). But for arbitrary $\lambda \notin \sigma_B(a)$ I can't prove that $(a - \lambda 1)^{-1}$ belongs to $A$ (and also I can't create a counterexample).

Comment: Take $A$ to be the continuous functions on the closed unit disc and $B$ the continuous functions on the unit circle. Let $a$ be the identity function. Then $\sigma_A(a)$ is the closed unit disc, while $\sigma_B(a)$ is the unit circle.

Comment: I don't have an  explicit counter-example but Rudin's FA has a lot of information on how spectra w.r.t. $A$ and $B$ compare and a sufficient condition for them to be equal.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy It seems to me that in Your example $A$ is not a subalgebra of $B$. Instead you have that $B$ is a quotient algebra $\frac{A}{I}$ where $I$ is an ideal of functions on unit disc that vanish on unit circle (since you have a canonical map from $A$ to $B$ which kernel is $I$).

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Also it seems to me that such an example is hard to construct from algebra $B = C(X)$ for some compact $X$. Assume that $A \subset C(X)$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra that contains $1$. Then for all invertible $a \in A$ we have that $a(X)$ is compact and $0 \notin a(X)$. Then $\frac{1}{z}$ can be approximated by polynomials of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ uniformly on $a(X)$ and therefore $a^{-1}$ can be approximated by polynomials of $a$ and $a^*$. So $a^{-1} \in A$. If I'm not mistaken this argument proves that $\sigma_A(a) = \sigma_B(a)$ for $C^*$-algebras $A \subset B$.

Comment: Well, I put the names in reverse. In my example, $B$ is included in $A$ by the function $f\in B\mapsto f|_T\in A$, where $T$ is the unit circle. Then the identity function on the unit disct $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$, such that $f(z)=z$ has a spectrum the unit disc $D$ as an element of $B$, while $f|_T:T\to\mathbb{C}$ as an element of $A$ has the unit circle for spectrum.

Comment: In general this example shows all that can happen: Suppose $B$ is the algebra of all continuous functions on the unit discs with a bunch of open discs (with disjoint closures) deleted. Let $A$ be the algebra of continuous function on the same disc with deleted discs, but we remove even more discs. One is included in the other by restriction. Then the spectrum of the indentity function on each is the corresponding disc with deleted discs. You see that the change in spectrum when the algebra is extended is by adding bounded connected components of the spectrum in the smaller algebra.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I don't think that restriction map $f \rightarrow f|_T$ is an inclusion. It has nontrivial kernel: the ideal of functions that vanish on unit circle $T$.

Comment: Then take the larger one to be the algebra of continuous functions on the unit circle that are restrictions of continuous functions on the closed unit disc, and analytic on the open unit disc. If two of them have the same restriction to the unit circle, then they must be the same function on the entire disc.